# Power BI - Counting the dates from one table that fall within the range of dates within another table, and matching ID

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables here. One has a unique identifier and a range of dates

[image]

And the other table has the same unique identifier and a list of activities

[image]

Please note, in the first table there are no duplicates in ID but in the second table there are plenty of duplicates.

In Power BI, I'd like to find a way to calculate an additional column (using DAX) in my first table that'll provide counts of how many activities fell into that date range but only among activities that have matching IDs.

[image]

I currently have the tables merged and it is a bit unruly given the size, so I'd like to keep the tables separated. These dates are American format (M/D/Y) if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try your data with three steps.

**Step1.** Connect the ID columns.

[image]

**Step2.** Change the date format from [here](https://www.cloudfronts.com/uncategorized/how-to-format-date-in-mm-dd-yyyy-format-in-power-bi/) which I reference.

**Step3.** DAX

[image]